# How to return only visible text when using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista. I have the following code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.co.uk"]
    #start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/formula1/28166984"]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.selector.xpath("//title")
        for titles in titles:
            body = response.xpath("//p").extract()
            body2 = str(body)
            body2.replace('\n', '')
            body2.replace('<p>', '')
            print body2
```

Which is working at returning the main text of the page I am trying to scrape, however it is also returning lots of HTML tags and carriage returns. In the last few lines you can see I have tried converting the variable 'body' into a string called 'body2', then using the replace function to remove some of the unwanted HTML, however this does not have the desired effect.

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving what I want to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use `remove_tags()` function from `scrapy.utils.markup` module

```
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags

# it'll print 'hello, world'
print remove_tags('<p>hello, world</p>')
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I've added the 'from scrapy.utisl.markup import remove tags' line, then at the body uses the syntax 'print remove_tags(body)', however this throws up an error. is that not the correct syntax for the print line?

Comment: you need to pass a `str` to `remove_tags()`.

Comment: excellent, nice one...that removed all the html tags perfectly. i dont suppose you know away to get rid of the \n \r 'u etc carriage returns from the screen print do you?

Comment: use regex to normalize whitespaces: `re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', html)`

Comment: i've used 'body3 = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', body2)' which im assuming will replace all instances of \r\n etc with a white space? however these characters are still being screen printed? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually, scrapy authors advise importing remove_tags directly from [w3lib html package](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#module-w3lib.html), as suggested in scrapy.utils.markup [module source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/markup.py)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
response.selector.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
```

Comment: thanks for replying. this did not remove the carriage returns unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try: **text()**

```
response.xpath("p/text()").extract()
```

This works for all tags not just for paragraph